# Can I rely on 'sizeof' in order to determine whether I'm using 32-bit OS or 64-bit OS

Tags: c++, c, 32bit-64bit, virtual-memory

Suppose I'm not sure how to check what OS I'm running on.

So I would like to determine that using the code below:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
size_t os_size = sizeof(void*) * CHAR_BIT;
```

Can I rely on it with 100%, or are there any caveats that I need to be aware of?

For example:

Is it possible that I have a compiler for 32-bit OS installed and working properly over 64-bit OS?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant and safe way to determine if architecture is 32bit or 64bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288189/elegant-and-safe-way-to-determine-if-architecture-is-32bit-or-64bit)

Comment: In any case it could only possibly know what the compiler is targeting, which has no relation to what it will actually run on.

Comment: @harold: So the size of a pointer merely indicates what size of virtual memory is supported by my compiler (and not by my OS)?

Comment: @barakmanos You can run 32-bit process in 64-bit OS, and the size of all your pointers will be 32 bits. Please explain why do you need to know whether your OS is 64-bit (and also specify which OS it is) to have more detailed answer.

Comment: @ Paul: My question was closed as duplicate. The answer to the linked question, suggests to use `size_t`. Don't these two (`size_t` and `sizeof void*`) go alongside each other???

Comment: Are we talking about runtime or compile time here?

Comment: @barakmanos It's not closed as duplicate (yet), it's only mentioned as possible duplicate. But still, please clarify, do you need to determine the architecture you target during compilation or the architecture you program actually runs on. There will be two different answers depending on that.

Comment: Smells like XY problem. How is the resulting value (suppose it is accurate) is going to be used?

Comment: @Paul: OK, I understand that I might be confusing OS, HW architecture (MMU I suppose), and compiler. So I guess that the actual question (or the following question) should be, is it possible to have different combinations of those three (in terms of "bit size")?

Comment: @void_ptr: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm interested in finding my OS type regardless of the "running state" of the code above. And in any case, I can't think of any other way to get the value of `os_size = sizeof(void*) * CHAR_BIT` without executing it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, because OP wants to find out what OS he is using right now, and true programmers write programms for this! :)

Comment: @SergeyA: Thank you for making my point :)

Comment: @SergeyA *because OP wants to find out what OS he is using right now*  How will that help if the OS supports running processes in multiple memory models?  Writing a program to solve this problem merely tells you how the program was compiled.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: But I didn't know that when I asked the question, right? I only suspected (or "feared") that the size of a pointer would only indicate what type of compiler I was using. Most of the answers and comments here have pretty much confirmed my concerns.

Comment: @barakmanos - Here's the thing though, expression `os_size = sizeof(void*) * CHAR_BIT` will not be _executed_. Instead, compiler will evaluate it at _compile time_, and embed the answer straight into the generated code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, not sure about Windows, but GCC on Linux will compile in OS 'bitnicity' by default.

Comment: @void_ptr: OK, so I can probably look into the binary image or something like that (if I wanted to work "real hard" instead of just running the program). But how does that make any difference between compile-time and runtime (in the context of my question)?

Comment: @barakmanos - I suggest you decide what you want to achieve, and rewrite the question, clearly stating the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: @rici: Thanks for the edit. Just learnt something new :)

Comment: @barakmanos: You need to find something that has nothing to do with your process, that only depends on the OS itself - maybe it's the existence of a certain file or directory (that only exists for 64-bit Windows), the contents of an environment variable, a "windows kernel API" function, etc. I don't know what it is. I only know it's definitely not `size_t` or `sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: @Brendan: I'm aware of the fact that there are plenty of non-programmatic ways for achieving this purpose. I asked this question because I wanted to know if this (programmatic) method could also be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you can have a C implementation where `char` are 32 bits, and `sizeof(char)` = `sizeof(int)` = `sizeof(long)` = 1, and probably `sizeof(long long)` = 2; IIRC some experimental implementation of C in Common Lisp (or maybe SBCL only) is doing similar stuff. Sadly, I forgot the details.

In practice, better use `<stdint.h>` giving `int32_t`, `int64_t`  and an `intptr_t` such that `sizeof(intptr_t)` = `sizeof(void*)`.

So the answer is *no*.

You might use `<limits.h>` and `INT_MAX` etc...

You could have a cross-compiler.... (e.g. compiling on a Linux x86-64 desktop for an 32 bits ARM android tablet with a cross [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

You might want to use things like [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf). Read about [GCC common predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html). Perhaps you want `__LP64__`

And you might have a Linux OS with 64 bits support on x86-64, but running in a `chroot`-ed environment (or container à la docker) providing a 32 bits environment (with 32 bits libc, 32 bits compiler, etc...). This is actually useful (e.g. to test on a 64 bits Linux laptop that your app can be compiled and executed on 32 bits). See e.g. [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot). And most Linux x86-64 systems are able to run 32 bits x86 ELF binaries (at least if they are statically linked). BTW, on my Linux/Debian/x86-64 system `gcc -m32` produces 32 bits object files and executables, but `gcc -m64` or just `gcc` gives 64 bits ...

On POSIX systems, to find out about your machine, use [uname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html). On Linux, you can even read and parse `/proc/cpuinfo` (and some other files under `/proc/`, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)).

I know nothing about Windows. If you are using it, you should give Linux a try.

Comment: Thanks, but does that "unanimously" guarantee the type of OS that I am running on? I'm aware of the fact that I might be confusing OS, HW architecture (MMU I suppose), and compiler. So in short, is it possible to have different combinations of those three (in terms of "bit size")? Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

as you already mentioned, you could have 32-bit compiler on 64-bit OS. On Linux there is even more interesting case called X32 ABI, where apps are special case of 32-bit, but support native 64-bit registers, native 64-bit math and so on.

Comment: OK, got it, thanks. I will wait for some more comments / answers / up votes to your answer in order to be sure. Thanks again :)

Comment: My question was closed as duplicate. The answer to the linked question, suggests to use `size_t`. Don't these two (`size_t` and `sizeof void*`) go alongside each other???

Comment: @barakmanos, size_t is a type, sizeof(void*) is value. How can the be the same thing?

Comment: @SergeyA: I didn't say they were **the same thing**, I said **they "go alongside each other"**, meaning that either they are both useful for my purpose or they are both not useful for my purpose!!!

Comment: @SergeyA: To be honest, I wanted to find out whether I have Win32 or Win64, and it was easier for me to open VS and give it a try. In retrospective, I suppose it would have been faster to search it up on the web instead of asking here... But I'm still interested in knowing the answer for the actual question. Thanks :)

Comment: You mean, you wanted to know if your local system you are using right now is 64bit or 32bit? :))))) Yes, writing a program and fiddling with sizeof(void*) is just the way true programmer should do this. Upvoting your question for the spirit!

Comment: @SergeyA I dont think this works. I have a 64 bit system and still, VS for a new project may be targeting the 32 bit platform, unless i tell it explicitly to target x64 platform in the project settings. All in all, these techniques permit to ask the compiler which platform it is targetting, that's it.